# Prevent CSS class from getting inherited by Child divs

Tags: html, css, class

I have the following div

```
<div class="ProductsDiv">
    <div>
        <img src=images/<%# Eval("GpuPic") %> />
        <br />
        <span> <%# Eval("GpuModel") %>  </span>
        <span>  <%# Eval("GpuPrice")%>  PKR  </span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

The class `ProductsDiv` contains style that sets `box-shadow` and `transition` to the div. I want to apply this class to outermost div only, but it gets applied to inner divs also. How do I specifically apply on outer div only?

Comment: Where is the CSS? Post them please

Comment: .ProductsDiv :hover {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

Answer (score 0):

The css you posted in comment have a typo mistake (may be), which is causing the problem  --

```
.ProductsDiv:hover { 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

There was a gap between 'ProductsDiv' and ':hover'.

Also, check this line -

```
<img src=images/<%# Eval("GpuPic") %> />
```

I've no experience on ASP. But i guess you wrote the code for img src is wrong. It should be something like this (You missed the inverted commas) --

```
<img src="images/<%# Eval('GpuPic') %>" />
```

Comment: No Bro...CSS code is fine in my application but typo mistake occured while copy pasting in the question

Comment: Check the edited solution. I faced the hover issue without the inverted comma. After i put them, its working nicely. At first solution, i completely removed the ASP codes.